# Inheritance, base classes, derived classes

Tags: c#, database, inheritance

I started from scratch again..  I am wondering if this following code will work writing and querying the database.  instead of getting and setting individual files of person such as city, state.   I would like a container class be able to do that..  and get and send that contactinfo object along with the other person data to the Main Program as I query a person.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class PERSON
    {
        public PERSON()
        {
            this.MANAGERs = new HashSet<MANAGER>();
            this.TRANSACTIONLISTs = new HashSet<TRANSACTIONLIST>();
        }
        public PERSON(string fName, string lName, ContactInfo contactInfo)
        {
            F_NAME = fName;
            L_NAME = lName;
            ContactInfo = contactInfo;
            this.MANAGERs = new HashSet<MANAGER>();
            this.TRANSACTIONLISTs = new HashSet<TRANSACTIONLIST>();
        }

        public ContactInfo ContactInfo { 

            get
            {
                ContactInfo.Phone = PHONE;
                ContactInfo.Email = EMAIL;
                ContactInfo.Address = new Address() { Street = ADDRESS, City = CITY, State = STATE, Zip = ZIP };
                return ContactInfo;

            }
            set
            {
                PHONE = ContactInfo.Phone;
                EMAIL = ContactInfo.Email;
                ADDRESS = ContactInfo.Address.Street;
                CITY =ContactInfo.Address.City;
                STATE = ContactInfo.Address.State;
                ZIP = ContactInfo.Address.State;
            }
        }

        public string F_NAME { get; set; }
        public string L_NAME { get; set; }
        public string ADDRESS { get; set; }
        public string CITY { get; set; }
        public string STATE { get; set; }
        public string ZIP { get; set; }
        public string PHONE { get; set; }
        public string EMAIL { get; set; }
        public decimal ID { get; set; }
        public string CURRENTMEMBER { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> TOTALDUE { get; set; }
        public string ISMEMBER { get; set; }
        public string PASSWORD { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<MANAGER> MANAGERs { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TRANSACTIONLIST> TRANSACTIONLISTs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are member and person two different tables?

Comment: just one table..    I need do a different table to identify managers and providers, but that's another challenge.

Comment: Since Member class inherits from Person class, all member instances are Person instances. ID is a property of Person class. Could you share the problem you are facing?

Comment: What do you mean by "have a problem .ID being recognized being part of the person class"? Clearly, `Person` has an `ID` property. If you're getting an error, state specifically what error you're getting, along with any additional details. Post a good, concise, complete code example. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Your design is a bit confusing to me. You inherit PERSON from PersonController and inside the PersonController (the parent class) you use PERSON (the child class) directly.
If I were you, I would  create a member class inherited from PERSON (my entity classes) and
a Controller class(T must be a PERSON or a subclass) that contains the methods related to PERSON.

Comment: Id would like to be able to change personcontroller so it would work all the entities in the database

Answer (score 0):

I have to say your current design is quite confusing and even if you manage to get it working, it will stay confusing. You should start by following the iDesign C# naming conventions all the way.

I'd start all over, all the way from `Person` class, and rethink what would be it's properties. And which of those properties would make up a nice, logical groups of information, making them classes as well.

One could come up e.g. the following.

```
public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
    }

    public Person(string fName, string lName, ContactInfo contactInfo)
    {
        FirstName = fName;
        LastName = lName;
        ContactInfo = contactInfo;
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public ContactInfo ContactInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Where `ContactInfo` is made out of phone number, email and `Address` class.

```
public class ContactInfo
{
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public int Zip { get; set; }
}
```

Now your `Member` would be a person but have additional properties attached to it. So it could look something like the following

```
public class Member : Person
{
    public Member(string fName, string lName, ContactInfo contactInfo)
        : base(fName, lName, contactInfo)
    {
        Id = 0;
        CurrentMember = "Y";
        TotalDue = 0;
        IsMember = "Y";
        Password = "Default";

        Managers = new HashSet<Manager>();
        Providers = new HashSet<Provider>();
        Transactionlists = new HashSet<Transactionlist>();
    }

    public decimal Id { get; set; }
    public string CurrentMember { get; set; }
    public decimal? TotalDue { get; set; }
    public string IsMember { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Manager> Managers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Provider> Providers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Transactionlist> Transactionlists { get; set; }
}
```

And what comes to "controller", `MemberController` or `PersonController`, would make more sense if it inherited from generic `Controller<T>`. Abstract base could be

```
public abstract class ControllerBase<T>
{
    public abstract void InsertOrUpdate(T obj);
}
```

And derived `MemberController`

```
public class MemberController : ControllerBase<Member>
{
    public override void InsertOrUpdate(Member obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Member");

        using (var context = new ChocDB())
        {
            var state = obj.Id == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;

            if (state == EntityState.Added)
                context.People.Add(obj);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Does this make any sense?

Comment: After stumbling around for a while, this makes a lot of sense.   I am trying to hang of generics, inheritance, databases, etc to work on this..   thank you for your help.

Comment: Modifying original question heavily is not cool. Now this answer is totally out of context and as such, totally useless to anyone else.